# ssh: connect to host pi adress port 22: Connection refused

Tags: networking, ssh, connection, cross-compilation, buildroot

i'm having some trouble when trying to connect to my raspberry b+. i have used **buildroot** and add dropBear package for SSH .
I gave the pi a static adress `10.42.0.5` and it's detected correctly in my ethernet network
here are some commands :

```
nmap -sP 10.42.0.0/24
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-01-25 02:23 WET
Nmap scan report for 10.42.0.1
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.42.0.5
Host is up (0.0069s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 2.61 seconds
```

The pi adress is `10.42.0.5`

For the ping it runs successfully

```
ping -c 3 10.42.0.5
PING 10.42.0.5 (10.42.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.42.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.83 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.0.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.03 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.0.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.03 ms

--- 10.42.0.5 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.035/3.303/4.836/1.158 ms
```

But whe trying ssh i get `connection refused`

```
ssh pi@10.42.0.5
ssh: connect to host 10.42.0.5 port 22: Connection refused
```

Note : i think this is not a duplicate since i have used BUILDROOT not raspbian or some other official distributions for raspberry

thanks

Comment: Did you start dropbear on the Pi? e.g. "dropbear -R"

Comment: Do you have sshd running on the pi?

Comment: @RichardPennington   i can't connect to the pi for now ! so i can't give you a response

Comment: @Havnar i can verify that because i couldn't connect to the pi

Comment: Connect directly with keyboard and screen and tell us. You probably miss-configured openssh. Then check the error logs, running services and configs.

Comment: @Jakuje Using HDMI I got : `starting dropbear sshd : [7.69..] NET : Registred protocol family 10`    `OK`

Answer (score 1):

Check netstat output on the RPI to check whether SSH server is open and listening. You can run following command and see whether dropbear is activily listening for connection

```
netstat -ta | grep ssh | grep -v grep
```

You might have enabled iptables(firewall) check whether you are not blocking the SSH port traffic (default port 22). List iptables rules to validate that

```
iptables -L
```